# wireless disabling after suspension

Tags: drivers, wireless, suspend

I did a fresh install of xubuntu 16.04.2 recently and now the wireless just seems to stop working at random.  So far, it seems to be during a session after coming out of suspension, though not right after, usually like an hour or two later.  Reboot fixes it for a while.  There are also issues with hanging and the mouse cursor disappearing after suspension.  `sudo lshw C- network` shows the wireless driver disabled:

```
*-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
       logical name: wlp12s0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:1f:3c:7d:32:5d
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwl3945 driverversion=4.8.0-41-generic firmware=15.32.2.9 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:29 memory:fe8ff000-fe8fffff
```

iwconfig says:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp12s0   IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

enp9s0    no wireless extensions.
```

and dmesg printed out this with some warnings/errors after the connection dropped...i don't really know what any of it means:

```
[22706.141103] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 5083 at /build/linux-hwe-bZV_oZ/linux-hwe-4.8.0/net/mac80211/driver-ops.c:39 drv_stop+0xfa/0x100 [mac80211]
[22706.141104] Modules linked in: hid_generic usbhid hid ccm gpio_ich dell_rbtn dell_wmi dell_laptop sparse_keymap dell_smbios dcdbas dell_smm_hwmon arc4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi iwl3945 iwlegacy snd_hda_codec_idt mac80211 snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core coretemp snd_hwdep cfg80211 snd_pcm snd_seq_midi kvm snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq pcmcia snd_seq_device irqbypass yenta_socket snd_timer pcmcia_rsrc snd pcmcia_core joydev input_leds soundcore lpc_ich serio_raw shpchp mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 algif_skcipher af_alg dm_crypt i915 psmouse firewire_ohci pata_acpi i2c_algo_bit firewire_core drm_kms_helper crc_itu_t tg3 syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt video fb_sys_fops wmi drm ptp pps_core
[22706.141138] CPU: 1 PID: 5083 Comm: kworker/1:1 Tainted: G        W       4.8.0-41-generic #44~16.04.1-Ubuntu
[22706.141139] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Latitude D630                   /0KU184, BIOS A09 04/03/2008
[22706.141152] Workqueue: events_freezable ieee80211_restart_work [mac80211]
[22706.141154]  0000000000000286 000000004e3454f5 ffff916afb0f7b78 ffffffff8622e043
[22706.141156]  0000000000000000 0000000000000000 ffff916afb0f7bb8 ffffffff85e8313b
[22706.141159]  00000027fb0f7b80 ffff916afb0b0700 ffff916afb0b0700 0000000000000000
[22706.141161] Call Trace:
[22706.141163]  [<ffffffff8622e043>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
[22706.141165]  [<ffffffff85e8313b>] __warn+0xcb/0xf0
[22706.141167]  [<ffffffff85e8326d>] warn_slowpath_null+0x1d/0x20
[22706.141181]  [<ffffffffc081999a>] drv_stop+0xfa/0x100 [mac80211]
[22706.141199]  [<ffffffffc084db33>] ieee80211_stop_device+0x43/0x50 [mac80211]
[22706.141216]  [<ffffffffc082f5c2>] ieee80211_do_stop+0x4c2/0x800 [mac80211]
[22706.141218]  [<ffffffff8669b46e>] ? _raw_spin_unlock_bh+0x1e/0x20
[22706.141220]  [<ffffffff865abbab>] ? dev_deactivate_many+0x20b/0x250
[22706.141236]  [<ffffffffc082f91a>] ieee80211_stop+0x1a/0x20 [mac80211]
[22706.141239]  [<ffffffff86579af9>] __dev_close_many+0x99/0x100
[22706.141240]  [<ffffffff86579bf1>] dev_close_many+0x91/0x140
[22706.141242]  [<ffffffff8657bf3a>] dev_close.part.82+0x4a/0x70
[22706.141244]  [<ffffffff8657bf7a>] dev_close+0x1a/0x20
[22706.141257]  [<ffffffffc0788d35>] cfg80211_shutdown_all_interfaces+0x45/0xb0 [cfg80211]
[22706.141275]  [<ffffffffc084b4d8>] ieee80211_handle_reconfig_failure+0x98/0xb0 [mac80211]
[22706.141293]  [<ffffffffc084dbd6>] ieee80211_reconfig+0x96/0xfb0 [mac80211]
[22706.141307]  [<ffffffffc081620e>] ieee80211_restart_work+0x8e/0xc0 [mac80211]
[22706.141309]  [<ffffffff85e9d88b>] process_one_work+0x16b/0x4a0
[22706.141310]  [<ffffffff85e9dc0b>] worker_thread+0x4b/0x500
[22706.141312]  [<ffffffff85e9dbc0>] ? process_one_work+0x4a0/0x4a0
[22706.141313]  [<ffffffff85e9dbc0>] ? process_one_work+0x4a0/0x4a0
[22706.141315]  [<ffffffff85ea3fa8>] kthread+0xd8/0xf0
[22706.141317]  [<ffffffff8669ba1f>] ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x40
[22706.141318]  [<ffffffff85ea3ed0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1e0/0x1e0
[22706.141319] ---[ end trace 7905e77c96f1b6a9 ]---
[22815.593040] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp12s0: link is not ready
[22816.143874] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xa5a5a5a2, s/b 0xf802020
[22816.143880] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
[22816.190603] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xa5a5a5a2, s/b 0xf802020
[22816.190606] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
[22816.237326] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xa5a5a5a2, s/b 0xf802020
[22816.237328] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
[22816.284047] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xa5a5a5a2, s/b 0xf802020
[22816.284050] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
[22816.330764] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xa5a5a5a2, s/b 0xf802020
[22816.330766] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
[22816.369691] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: Unable to initialize device after 5 attempts.
```

Hopefully some of that is useful.  Thankful for any help.

Comment: It's a bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1408963) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1627828). Recommendations found in those links but mostly workarounds. Installing an upstream kernel also on the [list](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds)

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't seem like there's a quality solution.  The workarounds I've tried so far haven't helped.  I don't really have the knowledge to be trying to work with the kernel, so I guess I'm just going to go with wired for now.

Answer (score 0):

https://igtek.tk/index.php/2016/05/11/fix-ubuntu-16-04-no-wireless-connection-after-suspend/

work for me! and the internet return normaly